# PHP IMAP: Compare emails CC with email stored in var

Tags: php, email

Right, so, im working on a system that goes through an email inbox, and gets the headers for each email and does stuff with them.

Im trying to compare an emails CC with an email set in a variable.
Problem is, when i echo out the CC, it shows as

> "someemail@gmail.com"

with double qoutes round it.
So i tried this code:

```
$hostemail = 'someemail@gmail.com'; $hostemail2 = '"'.$hostemail.'"';
```

where $hostemail2 is echoed out with double quotes round it, and tried to compare via

```
$header = imap_header($imap, $message); //Get headers
$cc = $header->ccaddress; //get the ccaddress header
if($cc == $hostemail2) { echo 'Well done'; } //if cc equals variable set before
else { echo 'Not gonna happen'; } //otherwise, yaknow
```

keeps giving me `Not gonna happen`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$header->ccaddress`, it was better to get the data using the CC array

`$cc = "{$header->cc[0]->mailbox}@{$header->cc[0]->host}";` where there would be no doubleqotes around it, and then you can do the `if` statement

`if ($cc2 == $hostemail) { echo "Hi";}`

For more information, visit [PHP: imap_headerinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php)